# HTML & CSS, how to center 3 divs inside a div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position 3 `div` in the center of another `div` but I'm having issues with the positioning. I tried using `verticle-align`, and negative margins but nothing seems to be working.

```css
.float-container {
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.float-child {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;  
}
```

```html
<div class="float-container">

  <div class="float-child">
    <div>Float Column 1</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="float-child">
    <div>Float Column 2</div>
  </div>

    <div class="float-child">
    <div>Float Column 3</div>
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: vertical alignment is not avalaible for floatting elements. Nowdays, for this kind of layout, grid or flex are efficient, flexible and easy to put in action. This is not a float job ;)

Answer (score 1):

example for my comment

> vertical alignment is not avalaible for floatting elements. Nowdays, for this kind of layout, grid or flex are efficient, flexible and easy to put in action. This is not a float job ;)

```css
.float-container {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  gap:30px;
  min-height:500px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.float-child {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
 
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="float-container">

  <div class="float-child">
    <div>Float Column 1</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="float-child">
    <div>Float Column 2</div>
  </div>

    <div class="float-child">
    <div>Float Column 3</div>
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

children only need now to be sized . alignement gap in between them is set from the flex parent. A min-height is given (500px inspirated from your padding 250px)

Answer (score 0):

An easy and "modern" way is to use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) if there are no limitations being set as part of a requirement to use `float`. As an example:

```css
.container {
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.child {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="child">
    Float Column 1
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    Float Column 2
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    Float Column 3
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float: left;` and in its place add `display: flex;`, `justify-content: center;`, `align-items: center;`, `flex-direction: row;`. For requirements like these, flex and grid are usually much simpler to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.float-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 250px;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid red;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.float-child {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 0 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;  
}
```

```html
 <div class="float-container">

    <div class="float-child">
      <div>Float Column 1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="float-child">
      <div>Float Column 2</div>
    </div>
  
      <div class="float-child">
      <div>Float Column 3</div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: Don't use float. you only have to do is that give display flex property to the main div and it will take all child div in center. hope you got it.